# Distribution of elements of a particular order in $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^*$

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, discrete-logarithms

Consider the group $G = (\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^*$, where $m$ is such that $G$ is cyclic.
Let $g\in G$ be some fixed generator, and let $a_1,\dots,a_{\varphi(m)}$ be an enumeration of the elements of $G$ in the "obvious way" --- specifically that when they're all viewed as elements of $\{1,\dots, \varphi(m)\}$, we have that $a_i < a_j\iff i<j$.

I'm interested in any concrete statements regarding how $\log_g a_i$ (the discrete logarithm with respect to $g$) behave.
A (strong) example of this might be something like:

> For any interval $[i, j]$, the elements $\log_g a_i,\dots, \log_g a_j$ are equidistributed throughout the group $G$.

I don't expect this to be true, but I expect some result that the discrete logarithm ``mixes elements well'' (as it's my understanding that a property along these lines is required for the discrete logarithm to be computationally difficult, which it's thought that it is).

1. Can this intuition be formalized at all?
2. Are there any provable results along these lines?

Comment: Is there any numerical data you could share?

Comment: @lhf unfortunately I have no explicit computations that I've done on this topic